# UIWebView not detecting redirect

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, uiwebview

I am building a Login API using OAuth2 Workflow. The server supports OAuth2 Authorization.
I open a OAuth2 authorization URL in the webview, which looks like `https://subdomain.domain.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=ios-app&redirect_uri=<redirect-uri>&response_type=code`

When the login is successful on the server, it opens a page whose URL is like `https://subdomain.domain.com/oauth2/authorize?state=&code=<authorization-code>`

For login to work I need to extract that authorization code from the URL and make an OAuth Token request using this code as a parameter.

I am trying to intercept the webview using `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` UIWebView delegate method. But this delegate method doesn't fire when the redirect occurs. I have set webview's delegate to `self`

How do I detect this redirect so that I am able to intercept it and extract the code from the URL?